# adb backup with build tools v23 fails

Tags: android, backup, adb

I'm trying to view files saved to the internal sdcard on my Android device in order to debug my application.

I used to be able to use adb backup to this this. I just upgraded to Build Tools v23, and now when I try to run adb backup from Terminal in OSX, I get a 'Bus error: 10' response and no backup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in ADB Build Tools 23.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your build.gradle file and make the changes as below,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.inzi.app"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Check for the compileSdkVersion (should be 23), buildTiilVersion (should be 23) and also the dependencies ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0')...

Let me know if it works...

And mark it as an answer so that it would be useful to others...